# how to track unique visitors in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET Tracking Code & Unique Visitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764976/asp-net-tracking-code-unique-visitors)

i am trying to create functionality for my asp.net 3.5 site to track unique visitors. I dont want to use an existing analytics package (googleanalytics for example). I was thinking of using cookies to store a unique id per user but this only logs a unique computer? I could also log the IP's but that reliable if an organisation uses proxies. What would be a good reliable solution?

Comment: There is no such solution to achieve what you are trying to do.  Even analytics packages like google analytics cannot have 100% precision.  Cookies is probably the closest option but you have the issues of users using different browsers, clearing their cookies, etc.

The only reliable option is as Valamas says to require users to login on every single access.   You should probably reconsider using those packages.  Don't reinvent the wheel.  You have very good customizations/configurations you can apply to google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your visitors login/identify themselves, you will not have a reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, use session id, and set a cookie with that session id. Next time they come, if they have the cookie with session id, you know they were there before. You can track them this way. You will still get people visiting that are repeats, but you can limit it to unique sessions, and minimize repeats this way. Anonymous browsing is anonymous. So you can only do it to an extent.