# Count online user using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Can any one help me. I've been looking on how to count how many users are login to my site but using asp.net - c#.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764976/asp-net-tracking-code-unique-visitors

Comment: @dash .. that has nothing to do with online users that I can see?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the intent of the question. For the number of active users, you can just use the Session_OnStart (+1 to a counter) and Session_OnEnd (-1 to a counter) events I guess. This will at least count the number of active sessions which should equate to the number of users online (but not necessarily active!)

Comment: This is a more approrpriate link I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218401/how-to-count-sessions-in-asp-net-server-application

Comment: As @dash suggested, this should work for you. you might like to handle Application_Error as well in case if there is an exception. Also, lock Application["LiveSessionsCount"] (from the above example) before making any change to this Application object.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx), you can simply call [Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getnumberofusersonline.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't use membership(as jrummell suggested):
You will have to implement your own counter as far as I know.
Just add an integer to the Application dictionary and increment it every time somebody logs in.
Decrement it in logoff and in the Session_End event(don't forget to check that the session that just ended had an active login - of course.

Comment: This will not work.  Session_End will not always be called when a session ends.  What if the app crashes for example?

Comment: If you use Application state then remember to wrap it in calls to `Lock()` and `Unlock()` to keep it thread-safe.  Also be aware that this will only work for a single server and not on a web farm.

Comment: @ChrisFulstow: There's also the [Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) method for simple cases like this.

Comment: @KierenJohnstone if the app crashes - all the sessions will die anyway.

Comment: @ChrisFulstow increment is an atomic operation, there should be no thread-safety issues here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tool to know that refer to [Online active users counter in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Online-Active-Users.aspx). Its easy to install. It had worked well for me.